# remove border from item checkbox in checkboxlist asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have doubts in removing the border of items in a `CheckBoxList` and have tried using the `CSS border: none` and even then, it did not work

in function BindData I get all item from PersonDB.mdf and put to checkBoxList

```
private void BindData() {

  string sQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Person] ORDER BY personID";
  //
  using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {

    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sQuery, connection)) {

      connection.Open();

      using(SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {

        while (sdr.Read()) {
          ListItem item = new ListItem();
          item.Text = sdr["personName"].ToString();
          item.Value = sdr["personID"].ToString();
          ListPerson.Items.Add(item);
        }
      }
      connection.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

and here I have the **asp.net** scripts to create `CheckBoxList` with ID **ListPerson**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"
 AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Person.aspx.cs" Inherits="Person" %>

  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
  </asp:Content>
  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <div>
      <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ListPerson" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox">
      </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
  </asp:Content>
```

and the design for `CheckBoxList` is show the `border` and I can´t remove

[image]

and the goal is to type so that style

[image]

any suggestion?

Comment: Can you inspect the element and see where exactly the `border` is getting applied and remove the border for the rule that has the border? Can you post the code of how it is getting rendered in HTML?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, this is partial page and the rendered HTML element is all in MasterPage.master

Comment: @PraveenKumar, is not need use jQuery maybe with css is the one of solution

Comment: When did I say the use of jQuery?

Comment: I got it. Kindly check the CSS version that's given in the answer. Why don't you read the page before you ask any questions further?

Comment: Ok, I will see the css, I tried and it´s don´t work `<asp:CheckBoxList ID="ListPerson" runat="server" CssClass="no-borders" </asp:CheckBoxList>` and css `.no-borders { border:0; }`